# An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm running with VS-2013 Premium with update 3. While debugging the code and when try to step into , I'm getting this error message box:
An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension

When entering the log file (the path is mentioned on the message), I'm get this exception:

```xml
<entry>
  <record>920</record>
  <time>2016/11/02 08:21:03.224</time>
  <type>Error</type>
  <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
  <description>System.InvalidOperationException:   EndBatchUpdate                called without BeginBatchUpdate being called&#x000D;&#x000A;
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Classification.Implementation.EditorFormatMap.EndBatchUpdate()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Classification.Implementation.ClassificationFormatMap.EndBatchUpdate()&#x000D;&#x000A;  
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.MarkerType.UpdateMarkerFormat(String markerName, IClassificationType classificationType)&#x000D;&#x000A;
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.MarkerType.EnsureLazyStateInitialized()&#x000D;&#x000A; 
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.MarkerManager.GetErrorTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)&#x000D;&#x000A;
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.MarkerManager.ErrorTaggerImplementation.GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)&#x000D;&#x000A;
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.&lt;GetTagsForBuffer&gt;d__5.MoveNext()
  </description>
</entry>
```

Same entry there more than 4 times. Even I have deleted the component cache model but problem is not resolved:

C:\Users\User name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0

others error are as below:

```xml
<entry>
  <record>891</record>
  <time>2016/11/02 08:21:02.023</time>
  <type>Error</type>
  <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
  <description>System.InvalidOperationException: IWpfTextView.TextViewLines is invalid.&#x000D;&#x000A;   
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.IWpfTextView.get_TextViewLines()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.AdornmentLibrary.TextMarkers.Implementation.TextMarkerVisualManager.OnFormatMappingChanged(Object sender, FormatItemsEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Classification.Implementation.ViewSpecificFormatMap.EditorFormatMapChanged(Object sender, FormatItemsEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Classification.Implementation.EditorFormatMap.SendChangedEvent()&#x000D;&#x000A;
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Classification.Implementation.EditorFormatMap.SetProperties(String key, ResourceDictionary properties)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Classification.Implementation.ClassificationFormatMap.SetExplicitTextProperties(IClassificationType classificationType, TextFormattingRunProperties properties)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Classification.Implementation.ClassificationFormatMap.AddExplicitTextProperties(IClassificationType classificationType, TextFormattingRunProperties properties, IClassificationType priority)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.FontsAndColorsHelper.UpdateLegacyMarkerClassification(IClassificationFormatMap classificationFormatMap, IClassificationType classificationType, ColorableItemInfo[] info)&#x000D;&#x000A;
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.MarkerType.UpdateMarkerFormat(String markerName, IClassificationType classificationType)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.MarkerType.EnsureLazyStateInitialized()&#x000D;&#x000A;
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.MarkerManager.&lt;GetClassificationTags&gt;d__15.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.TextMarkerViewTagger.&lt;GetTags&gt;d__0.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.&lt;GetTagsForBuffer&gt;d__5.MoveNext()</description>
</entry>

<entry>
  <record>853</record>
  <time>2016/11/02 08:19:10.020</time>
  <type>Error</type>
  <source>Color Theme Service</source>
  <description>The color &apos;Popup&apos; in category &apos;de7b1121-99a4-4708-aedf-15f40c9b332f&apos; does not exist.
  </description>
</entry>

<entry>
  <record>878</record>
  <time>2016/11/02 08:19:12.567</time>
  <type>Error</type>
  <source>Extension Manager</source>
  <description>Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.Desktop&apos; is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.0\DESKTOP SDK\...</description>
  <path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.1\DESKTOP SDK\</path>
</entry>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like an extension error. Pretty obscure issue with nothing to look at and no repro code.   Fwiw, how you could debug code that apparently also requires red squiggles to indicate syntax errors is hard to guess.  You'll have to call Microsoft Support if you can't live with it, but they'll first ask you to install the updates 4 and 5 so do that first.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to Tools--> Extensions and Update and disable all the addings from here. Restart the visual studio.
Problem will resolve.
Hope this will help others.

Comment: Go to Run, by pressing Windows+R. Type  Devenv.exe /SafeMode

Comment: @Dutt93 This helped me to fix the issue without restarting the machine again, Appreciate. :)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem after many years since this question was asked. So, this answer is for those who use Visual Studio 2019.

All you have to do is: `Extensions > Manage Extensions > Updates > Update All/Update [what you want]`.

Updating Visual Studio itself (if an update is available) is also advised.

**NOTE:** The `Extensions` menu is between `Tools` and `Window`.